# Launch image not appearing on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm programming an app for just iPhone and the launch images I've selected are not appearing when I specify the 'iOS-7 and later option' in the Xcode asset catalog editor.

When I uncheck the iOS-7 and later box and just use the 'iOS-6 and prior' option the images load fine.

Normally I would just go with this, however I get the warning from Xcode that 'iOS-7 images are required' so I'm worried the app may be rejected because of this.

Any suggestions to get around this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: oops, images above did not load

Comment: Hi you need to put Image name and size Like  320X480 , 640x960 , 640X1136 For iPhone..  Name is Like Default.png , Default@2x.png , Default-568h@2x.png.

Comment: @user1118089 Edit your question to add the images.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the names but still not loading. Do the files have to be in a certain place? I've put the images in 'supporting files'

Answer (score 1):

[image]Hi you need to put Image name and size For iPhone and iPad like attach image

Comment: Hmmm ....  still no luck. I've renamed them as you have and put the images in 'Supporting Files' folder then added them in the asset catalog section to the icons. I also tried not using the asset catalog adoption and did as you've done above but still they don't load. Thanks for the help though.